# Javascript Async Curry Function ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async.js, currying

Is there a way to make a curry function async?

Suppose I have the event handler function below (in my actual use case it is not an event handler), how could I update it to run async? My end goal is to have a curried function that I can await (it will be returning a promise).

```
foo = () => (event) => {
   this.setState({something:event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: "curry function" - you mean "arrow function", right?

Comment: hi georg, curry is a js way of creating customized functions, see [here](https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400) for some explanation

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind the 'await' keyword can only be used inside an async function.  So, even if you defined an async function - and you called that function from somewhere else - you won't be able to utilize the 'await' keyword.
I believe you're looking for this:

```
const foo = () => async (event) => {
    await performAnAsyncEvent(event);
    this.setState({something:event.target.value});
}
```